# Can the 4,000 years old mural etched into the Darband-i-Belula cliff, Iraq be linked to Sri Rama and Sri Hanuman?

Tags: ramayana

A mural found in Iraq:

> An Indian delegation undertook an expedition in Iraq in June to look
>   at a mural from circa 2000 BCE that the Ayodhya Shodh Sansthan
>   believes represents an image of Lord Ram.
>
> The mural is etched into the Darband-i-Belula cliff, overlooking a
>   narrow pass in Iraq’s Horen Shekhan area. It depicts a bare-chested
>   king holding a bow, a quiver of arrows at his side and a dagger or
>   short sword in his belt, and a supplicant with folded palms who the
>   Ayodhya Shodh Sansthan director thinks is an image of Hanuman.
>
> https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/lucknow/ram-footprints-on-iraqs-cliff-indian-embassy-tracks-mural/articleshow/69950327.cms

Can anyone have idea about this subject?

Comment: There could only be speculations about it but proving it won't be possible.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal: someone with knowledge in murals or archaeology may throw light on this subject:-)

Comment: Why not try asking this question in the StackExchange portal for History. you may find some information from there. https://history.stackexchange.com/tags

Comment: @V.Aggarwal: The article says Ayodhya Shodh Sansthan director had linked it Ramayana personalities.  That is why this question has been posted here.

Comment: True Indology refuted this. See https://swarajyamag.com/culture/sri-rama-in-iraq-this-pnoak-like-obsession-should-stop

Comment: @TheDestroyer: I am neither supporting nor refuting this idea.  I posted this here to obtain response of the members.  In one of my earlier posts I queried about lion-human also.https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/35391/3869

Comment: @TheDestroyer: Further, if we go by True Indology concept, they should stop linking Ram Sethu to Ramayana, which is a wrong concept.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Yes, today's Adam's bridge has no connection to Rama Setu mentioned in Ramayana. Check [this](https://youtu.be/AVhZz3CsNzk) video.

Comment: http://www.ancientpages.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/mitannikingdom14.jpg       I realised that this mittani art is depiction of Rama shooting vali, fighting sugreeva with mace

Comment: May be. @Aoi. T_015

Comment: It is a good question but why the downvotes?

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda: I don't know.  I am not a moderator to know, who downvoted it.:-).  May be some members do not want to think, just out of the way.

Comment: btw did you see this video of Subramaniyan Swamy speaking on this.. https://youtu.be/6cm0u_T4ilY

Comment: @Tejaswee: I have listened to Subramaniyan Swamy's observations on this issue.  He had expressed his opinion.  What I am looking for his an opinion of an expert in murals or archaeology.